# Hola. ¿Cómo se representa el carácter de ESC en C# para saber si está dentro de una cadena?

Tags: c#

Necesito saber si el carácter de parada o de stop (ESC) está presente en una cadena. Estoy programando con C#. ¿Alguien sabe como se introduce dicho caracter en el contains?

```
private void comprobarFinLinea(String ruta)
{
       StreamReader flujoLectura = new StreamReader(ruta);

       String lineaActual = "";

       while (!flujoLectura.EndOfStream) {

            lineaActual = flujoLectura.ReadLine();

            if (lineaActual.StartsWith("X4") && !lineaActual.Contains("")) {
                    MessageBox.Show("Esta linea no tiene ese caracter: " + lineaActual);
            }

}
```

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Lo que quieres es capturar la tecla ESC o el codigo de esa tecla?

Comment: El ASCII y el código de la tecla de ESC es 27 (decimal) o 0x1B.

Comment: Lo que quiero es el código de esa tecla. Gracias.

Comment: Los codigos -> https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+001B suerte!

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Muchas gracias.